# Incomplete \iffalse error with pgfmathparse in a caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, pgfmath, pgfmathparse

I am calculating a value with pgfmathparse, pgfmathroundto and pgfmathresult. It works all fine in normal text mode, but when I call the command in a caption, I get an "Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 14" error.

Here is a minimal working sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\myCalculation}[2]{\pgfmathparse{100 - #1 - #2}100 - #1 - #2 = \pgfmathroundto{\pgfmathresult}\pgfmathresult}

\begin{document}

Calculate \myCalculation{30}{20.11}. % this works.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Calculate \myCalculation{30}{20.11}.} % this returns an error.
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This also happens for a table caption, btw. While it works inside the table itself, a table caption calling the function raises the error again.

Is there a way to make such a command work in a caption, or is this a known bug?

Comment: I'd assume that `\pgfmathparse` is fragile and just cannot be used inside captions. I would also not make the calculation like that. There is a variant of `\pgfmathparse` that stores the result in a macro given by the user. That might be better, then run the calculation outside `\caption` and use the macro with the result in the caption (untested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a protected command (which `\pgfmathparse` isn't) encapsulating the computation and use the more accurate floating point library that's included in the LaTeX kernel.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myCalculation}{mm}{%
  $100 - #1 - #2 = \fpeval{round(100-#1-#2,\myAccuracy)}$%
}
\newcommand{\myAccuracy}{2}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Test}

Calculate \myCalculation{30}{20.11}. % this works.

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Calculate \myCalculation{30}{20.11}.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]